# WPF animation margin binding

Tags: wpf, animation, data-binding

Is there a way to bind a Thickness animation to the UserControls parent containers width in a way that the animation makes the UserControl slide in from the left?

I know Width is an int and the target property is a margin which are not the same type, and I know that you should be using some kind of ValueConverter but mine doesn't seem to be working right.

below is my very poor, but best attempt at getting this right. Which didn't work. Are there any better more simpler ways of doing this? preferably without the need of a converter, and a pure xaml solution.

```
<Window>
    <Grid> <!-- Main Window Container -->
        <UserControl x:Name="ParentControl" Content="{Binding Window}" />
    </Grid>
</Window>

<UserControl>
    <UserControl.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Loaded">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <ThicknessAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ucDashboardView" 
                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin" 
                                    From="{Binding Width, ElementName=ParentControl, 
                                    Converter=cnv:MarginWidthConverter}"  
                                    To="0" Duration="0:0:1"/>
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
    </UserControl.Triggers>

    <!-- Just so we can see something right now -->
    <Grid Margin="50" Background="Gainsboro"/>
</UserControl>
```

and then the C# converter

```
public class MarginWidthConverter : BaseValueConverter<MarginWidthConverter>
{
    public override object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return new Thickness(-(int)value, 0, (int)value, 0);
    }

    public override object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: "I know Width is an int" - it is not. Width is a double. Besides that you probably want to bind to ActualWidth.

Comment: @Clemens ActualWidth is not a dependency property and doesn't notify on changed value as far as I know. Unless you write a SizeObserver attached Dependecy Property. Like the one here [WPF ActualWidth and ActualHeight Size observer](https://gist.github.com/jrgcubano/54ecbc61cbfaaa83b4dd14de03adf296)

Comment: @PouyaAbadi It is a readonly dependency property, and of course notifies about value changes.

Comment: @Clemens I stand corrected, yes Width is a double, my bad. Also I did try with ActualWidth but that didnt seem to make a difference. And I think it is because of the way I am trying to load UserControls from code and then adding them to a bound list of usercontrols on the Main Window